# Python read file into numpy array of list?

Tags: python, numpy

How to read a file containing text which may not be of same length each line as ascii numbers.

ex

```
APORRADASD
ASDSDASD
```

as

```
0 -> [065,080,079,082,082,065,068,065,083,068]
1 -> [065,083,068,083,068,065,083,068]
```

and then subtracting it by 65(as only capitalised letters are present).
When I try using for loops for reading each line and then subtracting makes the process very slow(as the file is around 300+MB)

```
data = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', dtype=np.object_)
for x in range(0,data.shape[0]):
    data[x] = [c - 65 for c in data[x]]
```

Comment: Please add some code to demonstrate what you've tried.

Comment: There are plenty of materials on line to show you how to read from a file, and how to convert characters to ASCII codes.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: `numpy` isn't going to help you with that.  The `numpy` `csv` readers use regular Python `readline` and `split`.  And they expect the lines to have a common length.  And for most processing an object dtype array of lists is slower than the equivalent list of lists.

Comment: OMG, I'm sorry I had thought I had added the code, -5Downvotes!!!! The problem is as the file size is large it takes a lot of time, my method must e inefficient... so suggestions

Comment: Used this way `genfromtxt` doesn't do anything special.  Have you tried getting the strings with a simple: `data = open(file).readlines()`?

Comment: Have you tried to figure out whether the inefficiency is in reading the text file or in conversion from strings to numbers?

Comment: @hpaulj For Reading the files there is not much difference in time(does it in a few seconds) but the for loop to convert it into numbers and subtract takes around 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ascii_conv = []
foo = "APORRADASD"
bar = list(foo)
for n in bar:
    ascii_conv.append(ord(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your sample a couple of 1000 times and tested several options.

An 'all in one loop' is to read and parse the lines together:

```
In [159]: with open('stack48307975.txt','rb') as f:
     ...:     data=[np.array(list(l.strip()))-65 for l in f]
     ...:        
In [160]: len(data)
Out[160]: 4000
In [161]: data[:3]
Out[161]: 
[array([ 0, 15, 14, 17, 17,  0,  3,  0, 18,  3]),
 array([ 0, 18,  3, 18,  3,  0, 18,  3]),
 array([ 0, 15, 14, 17, 17,  0,  3,  0, 18,  3])]
```

That saves on the `getfromtxt` overhead.  Roughly equivalent is to

Reading all, and then parsing:

```
In [162]: with open('stack48307975.txt','rb') as f:
     ...:     dataB = f.readlines()
     ...:    
In [163]: len(dataB)
Out[163]: 4000
In [164]: [[c-65 for c in row.strip()] for row in dataB][:3]
Out[164]: 
[[0, 15, 14, 17, 17, 0, 3, 0, 18, 3],
 [0, 18, 3, 18, 3, 0, 18, 3],
 [0, 15, 14, 17, 17, 0, 3, 0, 18, 3]]
```

In Py3 I have to open with `rb` to get bytestrings, which then allows us to convert with `c-65`.  If I load with `r` mode I get unicode strings, and have to use `ord(c)`.

I could `read` the whole file into one string, and convert that to an array:

```
In [165]: with open('stack48307975.txt','rb') as f:
     ...:     dataAll=f.read()
     ...:         
In [166]: len(dataAll)
Out[166]: 40000
In [167]: dataAll[:13]
Out[167]: b'APORRADASD\nAS'
In [168]: dataOne =np.fromiter(dataAll,dtype='uint8')
In [169]: dataOne.shape
Out[169]: (40000,)
In [170]: dataOne[:13]
Out[170]: array([65, 80, 79, 82, 82, 65, 68, 65, 83, 68, 10, 65, 83], dtype=uint8)
```

But splitting this into lines takes a bit of fiddling

```
In [171]: idx = np.where(dataOne==10)[0]
In [172]: idx
Out[172]: array([   10,    19,    30, ..., 39979, 39990, 39999], dtype=int32)

In [175]: np.split(dataOne-65, idx)[:3]
Out[175]: 
[array([ 0, 15, 14, 17, 17,  0,  3,  0, 18,  3], dtype=uint8),
 array([201,   0,  18,   3,  18,   3,   0,  18,   3], dtype=uint8),
 array([201,   0,  15,  14,  17,  17,   0,   3,   0,  18,   3], dtype=uint8)]
```

Or to better handle the `\n`:

```
In [178]: idx0=[0]+(idx[:-1]+1).tolist()
In [179]: [dataOne[i:j]-65 for i,j in zip(idx0, idx)][:4]
Out[179]: 
[array([ 0, 15, 14, 17, 17,  0,  3,  0, 18,  3], dtype=uint8),
 array([ 0, 18,  3, 18,  3,  0, 18,  3], dtype=uint8),
 array([ 0, 15, 14, 17, 17,  0,  3,  0, 18,  3], dtype=uint8),
 array([ 0, 18,  3, 18,  3,  0, 18,  3], dtype=uint8)]
```

I've done some timings, but it'll make more sense if you did your own.